# ViewModel returns same values for all 500+ records to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am new to using ViewModels, I have a new list here and am adding items to it by looping though a database table. The issue is that all the records that come back are identical using the same record over and over. What could be the issue and is this a good way to accomplish filling with data and Passing a ViewModel or is there a better way? Right now it returns about 500 records with the same data.

```
public class DimCustomersController : Controller
{
    private AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities db = new AdventureWorks_MBDEV_DW2008Entities();

    public ActionResult CustomersIndexVM()
    {
        List<DimCustomersIndexViewModel> CustomerList = new List<DimCustomersIndexViewModel>();

        DimCustomersIndexViewModel CustomerItem = new DimCustomersIndexViewModel();
        foreach (var m in db.DimCustomers.ToList())// cold do for loop up to count
        {
            CustomerItem.Title = m.Title;
            CustomerItem.FirstName = m.FirstName;
            CustomerItem.MiddleName = m.MiddleName;
            CustomerItem.LastName = m.LastName;
            CustomerItem.BirthDate = m.BirthDate;
            CustomerItem.MaritalStatus = m.MaritalStatus;
            CustomerItem.Suffix = m.Suffix;
            CustomerItem.Gender = m.Gender;
            CustomerItem.EmailAddress = m.EmailAddress;
            CustomerItem.AddressLine1 = m.AddressLine1;
            CustomerItem.AddressLine2 = m.AddressLine2;
            CustomerItem.Phone = m.Phone;
            //other columns go here
            CustomerList.Add(CustomerItem);
        }

        return View("CustomersIndexVM", CustomerList);
    }
```

Comment: Apart from initializing the view model inside the loop as per the answers, you can also just use `var CustomerList = db.DimCustomers.Select(x => new DimCustomersIndexViewModel { Title = x.Title, FirstName = x.FirstName, ...... }.ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line needs to be inside the loop:

`DimCustomersIndexViewModel CustomerItem = new DimCustomersIndexViewModel();`

The reason is that you want a new view model for each customer, but instead you are currently creating only one view model and changing its properties. When you add it to the list, you are not adding a copy; you are adding the same view model you already added.

This code would work if `DimCustomersIndexViewModel` was a struct, because structs are just a bag of values that have no inherent identity and they are copied rather than referenced. [(Technical comparison.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) But it's a class (as it should be), with a unique identity, so you're adding a *reference* to the single view model into the list over and over. `Customerlist[0]` and `CustomerList[1]` and all the other items point to the same `DimCustomersIndexViewModel` object instance, whose properties are then overwritten and left equal to the very last customer.

By moving this line *inside* the loop, you are creating a separate `DimCustomersIndexViewModel` for each customer, each with its *own* set of properties, and `CustomerList` contains references to many different `DimCustomersIndexViewModel` object instances.

Once you have solid experience with this concept, a future step could be to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) so that you don't have to maintain a list of all properties in your code here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you add the *same* reference object during each iteration of your loop.  That object never changes (you never `new` it up again), but you change the properties on the object. Then you add that object over and over.  You need to new up that object each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue; amazing how I missed the simple stuff :)